# Testfairy SDK not integrated while uploading apk in Testfairy

Tags: android, testfairy

I am uploading android apk file through Testfairy so that I can see logs when required. But after uploading, it says "Testfairy SDK not integrated in build, No recordings will be performed". Please suggest why this is happening.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. The reason behind the issue was, TestFairy does not integrate its SDK for two reasons.

1) If the apk method count is more than 65,536.

2) Because of Instant-run.

I was having the issue with Instant-run as my apk method count was less than 65,536.

Solution: 
Goto Android Studio --> Preferences --> Build,Execution,Deployment (from Left panel) --> Instant Run --> Uncheck the check boxes in the Right Panel --> Apply --> Ok.

Now try to upload the .apk file through TestFairy.